# lambda でVPCを設定した場合にSQSにmessageを追加できない

Tags: aws, aws-lambda

lambdaでVPCを設定しRDSから必要な値を取得してSQSにmessageを送信しようとしていますが、以下のメッセージが表示されlambdaがタイムアウトしてしまいます

```
We are unable to display results and logs for invocations that take longer than 60 seconds. You can view the results and logs for the function in CloudWatch once the function completes executing.
```

VPCを外すとSQSに値は正常に追加されます

またSQSにSNS経由でなら可能かもと思い試しましたが同様の現象で追加できませんでした、VPCをはずすとSNSにpushできました

Comment: 同一 vpc にあるかとか、セキュリティグループの outbound, inbound が適切に設定されているかなど、原因が考えられますが、それらの情報の追記はできますでしょうか？http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: RDSはlambdaと同じVPC内にいます、SQS、SNSはVPCの設定がないのでVPCの設定はしていません
セキュリティグループの設定についてはフルアクセスにしています

Comment: natゲートウェイを設定する必要があるかもしれません

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

Answer (score 0):

VPCにNATゲートウエイを設定するか、VPCエンドポイントを定義するかのどちらかになるかと思います。
いくつもエンドポイントを設定すると料金がかさむので、NATゲートウエイの方が安くなります。